# JS displaying photos no matter what the extension is

Tags: javascript, png, jpeg, photo

My JS problem is pretty simple: I have a piece of code that reads and displays photos from a given PC folder. Problem is, I don't know how to make it display all types of photos, without taking in account what extension they have. Currently, it only displays .jpg files.

This is how I wrote it:

```
var index = 1;
var tempImg = new Image();
tempImg.onload = function(){
    appendImg();
}
var loadImg = function(index){
    tempImg.src = 'img/' + index + '.jpg';
}
var appendImg = function(){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = tempImg.src;

    document.body.appendChild(img);
    loadImg(index++);

}
loadImg(index);
```

Comment: How do you get the index and how would you know what the extension is? Only the server knows that, unless you have a limited list you can guess from

Comment: @mplungjan edited for more of the code :). Also, I don't work with any server, I'm only doing it locally and that's all I need

Comment: If you do it locally you could use the filesystem api https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it locally you could use the filesystem api

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

If not and you have a folder of

```
0.jpg
1.gif
2.png
...
```

then if you know the types of images you can encounter you can try each

```
<style>
img { width:50px }
</style>
<script>
const folder = "img/"; 
const maxImages = 4; // I think there are at least 4 images in the folder
const suffix = ["jpg","gif","png"]; 
let cnt = 0, idx = 0, container, img;
const loadImage = () => {
  if (idx >= maxImages) return; 
  if (cnt ===0) img = new Image();
  img.onload=function() {
    var saveImg = document.createElement("img");
    saveImg.src = this.src;
    saveImg.title = folder+idx+"."+suffix[cnt];
    container.appendChild(saveImg);
    idx++;
    cnt=0; 
    console.log("new image");
    loadImage()
  }
  img.onerror = function() {
    console.log("failed to load",folder+idx+"."+suffix[cnt]);
    cnt++; // try next suffix
    if (cnt >= suffix.length) {
      console.log("gave up")
      var saveImg = document.createElement("img");
      saveImg.title = folder+idx+" not found";
      saveImg.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
      container.appendChild(saveImg);
      cnt=0; idx++;
    }
    loadImage();
  }
  console.log("trying to load", folder+idx+"."+suffix[cnt]);
  img.src = folder+idx+"."+suffix[cnt];
}

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  container = document.getElementById("imagecontainer");
  loadImage();
});


</script>
<div id="imagecontainer"></div>
```

Comment: I made a complete version. It can ONLY handle images from 0-n.ext where ext is gif, png, jpg - it will stop when there are no more images if you set maxImages to a high enough number

Comment: I removed the stop test - that was when I did not stop looping - it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

I assume your pictures are numbered from 1 onwards. This makes it possible to just use an incrementing index number followed by a hardcoded file extension to load the pictures but as you realized fails if the extension is not .jpg.

What you could do is store the exact filename including the extension inside an array and use the index number to reference a particular picture inside.

```js
var index = 0;
var myPictures = ["1.jpg", "2.png", "3.png"];
var tempImg = new Image();
tempImg.onload = function() {
  appendImg();
}
var loadImg = function() {
  tempImg.src = 'img/' + myPictures[index];
}
var appendImg = function() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = tempImg.src;

  document.body.appendChild(img);
  if (index + 1 < myPictures.length) {
    index++;
    loadImg();
  }


}
loadImg();
```

Comment: But the issue is unknown suffix

Comment: Well my assumption is that Andra just doesn't know how to specify different file extensions.

Comment: That would've been fine but I'd like not to hard code the photos, as I'm trying to make a dynamic code, usable on whatever folder, with however many photos in it, could be 10, could be 200.

Comment: In that case  mplungjan's answer should be the way to go.